# In marketing, what's the difference between "leads" and "prospects"

Tags: business-language

In the Oxford Dictionary online

> *[lead](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead)*
>   1.2 Someone or something that may be useful, especially a potential customer or business opportunity:
>
> *[prospect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prospect)*
>   2 A person regarded as likely to succeed or as a potential
>   customer, client, etc.

I'm not sure which one is closer to signing contact?

Comment: I think you mean prospects? There seems to be some overlap in the meaning of the two terms, and there are probably variations in the technical definitions that individuals and organizations place on the terms.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Shawn. Please, notice how I added research to your question. Take a look at it and see if you are closer to understanding. We can't take the place of a good dictionary in your life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "perspective," but "prospect."

**prospect**: a potential buyer or customer

**lead**: tip, clue

I feel that a *prospect* is closer to a **/closure/contract/**, but not by much.

Comment: In marketing, the meaning of expressions is certainly influenced by time, situation and goal. A lead will quickly become a prospect when the marketeer is describing them in his end-year review...